# angular material date-time picker - format the input with date and 24 hour time

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker
for datetime picker for my angular material.io app

I want to format my date input to show time in 24 hours format(02/15/2020 21:05) input right now -->[image: present]

Documentation talks about creating a custom adapter by extending NgxMatDateAdapter but to extend that I have to implement 20 functions in that class.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's directly available.
You can read below article if you want to achieve this.

https://medium.com/@amandeepkochhar/angular-material-datepicker-set-custom-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-5c0f4340e57

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2qoxi-iy68bi?file=app%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts) to get your answer.

```
import {MAT_DATE_FORMATS} from '@angular/material';
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};
```

Write the code in your component provider

```
 providers: [
       {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this would help you..**

You should set one option **`enableMeridian`**.
Because this `enableMeridian` means : `Whether to display 12H or 24H mode.` and it's value if `true or false`. By default it is `false`..

So I think your code will be like this ..

```
const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: "l, LTS"
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: "l, LTS",
    monthYearLabel: "MMM YYYY",
    dateA11yLabel: "LL",
    monthYearA11yLabel: "MMMM YYYY",
    enableMeridian: true
  }
};
```

**You can refer this link.**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker